# Dynamically added view does not call onDraw after invalidate()

Tags: android, kotlin

When I programmatically added `MyView` and call `myView.invalidate()`, `onDraw` is not called on demand. But when I put it directly on `R.layout.activity_main` it works like no problem.

On my activity

```
val myView: MyView
    get() = MyView(this)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    container.addView(myView)
}
```

MyView

```
class MyView : View{
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        Log.e("MyView","onDraw")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see, this is the problem

```
val myView: MyView
   get() = MyView(this)
```

This will create new instance of `MyView` every time I use the variable `myView`

So I make it like this, now it works.

```
    lateinit var myView: MyView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        myView = MyView(this)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph)
        container.addView(myView)
    }
```